# How do I overlap 2 images based on a mouse click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, overlay

The desired behavior is to be able to click in a grid and the overlaid image will stay in its correct square. However, when resizing the browser window, the positioning gets messed up (see link below).

Link to demo of the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fbPlQLvHLs

```
function onClick(e) {
    let xPos = e.clientX;
    let yPos = e.clientY;

    var newImg = document.createElement("img");
    newImg.src = 'https://www.pngmart.com/files/4/Circle-PNG-File.png';
    newImg.style.position = "absolute";
    newImg.style.left = xPos + "px";
    newImg.style.top = yPos + "px";
    newImg.style.width = "35px";
    document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(newImg);
```

```
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
    <img id="my-image" src="https://www.guineapigcagesstore.com/resize/Shared/Images/Product/Standard-Grid/standard-grid.jpg?bw=1000&w=1000&bh=1000&h=1000" 
    alt="img" width="300px" position="relative" ></img>
</div>
```

Styling for wrapper:

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please share your styling for `#wrapper` and `.wrapper`. I can only assume that the image is aligned to the center. What you should do is make the dots relative and the position should be based of the wrapper and not document. I would also recommend looking into canvas, but that's another topic.

Comment: I just updated to include it. You are right that it is only aligned to the center. How would I make the position relative to the wrapper?